# Keep value used in closure for later use

Tags: rust, callback, closures

```
fn callback_test() {
    let image = HtmlImageElement::new().unwrap();
    let callback: Closure<dyn Fn()> = {
        Closure::wrap(Box::new(|| {
            image.set_src("foo");
        }))
    };
    image.set_onload(Some(&callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
}
```

Here is a exemple of what I'm trying to achieve. If I don't use the move keyword before the closure declaration I get a lifetime error, and if I use it I can't assign my callback later in the function. What is the correct way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `.clone()` it.

The `Closure` only works with functions that are `'static`, meaning they can't hold references to local variables. If it were to allow that, then calling that closure after `callback_test()` completes would try to use a dangling reference since `image` has already been dropped.

So `move`-ing it into the closure is the right move. And since you have to use it again after creating the closure, you will need two copies to work with.

Try this out:

```
fn callback_test() {
    let image = HtmlImageElement::new().unwrap();
    let callback: Closure<dyn Fn()> = {
        let image = image.clone();
        Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
            image.set_src("foo");
        }))
    };
    image.set_onload(Some(&callback.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
}
```